# How to call specific column when using eloquent relationship one to many in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I wanna ask something about the eloquent relationship in laravel, well this is first time I using this method, usually, I used join table to get data in relationship, for one condition and this is project must using relationship eloquent but I still not understand how to make the table connect to each other, well I already make some query and method in model and controller like this :

**Item Model (this is parent table)**

```
class Item extends Model
{
   protected $primaryKey = "id_item";
  
   protected $fillable = [
      'name_item', 'created_by', 'edited_by'
   ];

   public function type_of_items() {
      return $this->hasMany('App\TypeOfItem', 'type_id_item');
   }
}
```

**Type Of Item Model (this is child table)**

```
protected $primaryKey = "id_type_item";

protected $fillable = [
   'type_id_item', 'code_type_of_item', 'type_of_item', 'created_by', 'edited_by'
];

public function items() {
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Item');
}
```

**In Controller**

```
<?PHP

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

use App\Item;
use App\TypeOfItem;
use Validator;

public function getData() {
   $getData = TypeOfItem::with('items:id_item,name_item')->get();
   dd($getData);
}
```

well for the result when I try `dd` my data is nothing an error result, but why my data only show field in `type_of_item` and not show data in my `items` table, am I make a some mistake in my query? If yes, where and what should I do to make my query can call all my field in 2 tables, thank you

**result `dd` :**

```
array:8 [
    "id_type_item" => 1
    "type_id_item" => 30
    "code_type_of_item" => "H001"
    "type_of_item" => "Hardisk SATA - 500GB"
    "created_by" => "Jhony"
    "edited_by" => "Jhony"
    "created_at" => "2021-02-04 16:49:30"
    "updated_at" => "2021-02-04 16:49:30"
  ],
 array:8 [
    "id_type_item" => 2
    "type_id_item" => 29
    "code_type_of_item" => "T001"
    "type_of_item" => "Black Inc - 500ml"
    "created_by" => "Jhony"
    "edited_by" => "Jhony"
    "created_at" => "2021-02-04 16:49:30"
    "updated_at" => "2021-02-04 16:49:30"
  ]
```

Comment: Try specifying the fk in the `belongsTo()` as well. `belongsTo('App\Item', 'type_id_item')`

Comment: okey sir, I did it, thanks for the suggestion, well can you explain a little bit how eloquent work sir?

Comment: The documentation will do a better job at explaining than I could in comments. If that was the problem, it was because of naming conventions.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: okay sir, thank you